# Firefox cannot detect GPU (libEGL segfault)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, firefox, opengl

EDIT: The cause (or one cause) appears to be a segfault in `libEGL-nvidia`, which I guess causes `glxtest` to fail, which causes firefox to assume the drivers are faulty (which they could partially be). I have received an update to firefox 111, but it didn’t fix the problem.

WebGL has suddenly stopped working in Firefox. My drivers seem fine. They're all detected properly, even by Firefox if I force it to. The problem appears to be that `glxtest` fails because it can't detect my GPU, which results in `glxInfo` blocklisting support.

Pastebin with full troubleshooting log (WebGL force-enabled): https://pastebin.com/cX6ZWFhL

Startup error:

```
[GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI
[GFX1-]: glxtest: process failed (received signal 11)
```

Errors without force-enabled WebGL:

```
# WebGL 1 driver renderer
WebGL creation failed: 
* WebglAllowWindowsNativeGl:false restricts context creation on this system. ()
* Exhausted GL driver options. (FEATURE_FAILURE_WEBGL_EXHAUSTED_DRIVERS)

# WebGL 2 driver renderer
WebGL creation failed: 
* AllowWebgl2:false restricts context creation on this system. ()
```

`lspci -vv` output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2507 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device c978
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 138
    Region 0: Memory at 50000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8G]
    Region 3: Memory at 6200000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 51000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

`glxinfo` output:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    <extension list clipped for readability>
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    <extension list clipped for readability>
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 8192 MB
    Total available memory: 8192 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 7744 MB
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.85.05
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    <extension list clipped for readability>

OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.85.05
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
    <extension list clipped for readability>

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 525.85.05
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    <extension list clipped for readability>
```

`nvidia-smi` output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.05    Driver Version: 525.85.05    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   44C    P8     7W / 130W |    206MiB /  8192MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place, it's just been really difficult to find help and the issue is super frustrating.

Comment: Most likely, your video drivers were just updated. Reboot the machine.

Comment: @WhiteOwl I don't think I've had a driver update and I have rebooted. The problem is still there (and worse, firefox hangs for a few seconds before starting now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be fixed in version 114. I've reset the settings I used when I first got this issue to try to get Firefox to use WebGL and it still works without that. I haven't seen this get mentioned anywhere so I don't know if this was caused by another fix or if something on my end changed, but the problem is gone for me.